# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ML.Api'

Tags: c#, ml.net

When I trying to use LoadFromEnumerable
to load my dataset which is implemented as List
I got the following error (as mentioned in the title)

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ML.Api, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified

I have updated to the latest version of `ML.net` packages but I still not find the documentation of `Microsoft.ML.Api`

```cs
var mlContext = new Microsoft.ML.MLContext();
var trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dataset);
```

EDIT

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e6i6.png)

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to reproduce this? So you open Visual Studio, New Project, Console Application, then you add a nuget package I guess? And then you paste those two lines in the main method and compile? And it compiles and then crashes with the error above? Or did you do something else?

Comment: Double check that you're targeting x64 in your project, as well.

Comment: Yes just like what you mentioned. Actually I got my data from database by connection string which may cause the problems. However, I try to follow this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-data-ml-net#load-data-from-other-sources
but I still got the same error

Comment: yes targeting x64

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error with a classic/old "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)".
 
Needed 1 1/2 days to figure out how to solve it. :-(

Finally I solved it and would like to share it:

1. Select your program -> right mouse click -> "Properties" -> "Build" tab
   -> Two things to do here:
   1a) Set "Platform target" to "x64".
   1b) Click "Advanced" button at the bottom and check whether the "Language Version" contains minimum "C#7.1".
   But set "Language Version" to "C# latest major version (default)".
2. Read this careful:
   Select "References" of your program -> right mouse click
   -> "Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...".
   Follow the wizard ...

The really bad thing is that the context menu entry **"Migrate packages.config to PackageReference..."** is only available in case a NuGet package is already added to your program!
So in case you get the above error at run time
but this context menu entry is not shown
install a dummy NuGet package of your choice (prefer a small one!).
Follow then step 2.
Remove then the prior installed "dummy NuGet package"
(Select therefore "References" of your program -> right mouse click -> "Manage NuGet Packages" ...)
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.ML.Api` was an old assembly name that has been removed. Can you ensure all your references to ML.NET are up-to-date? The latest release is version `1.3.1` for stable packages (which is most of them), and `0.15.1` for preview packages.

If that doesn't help you, please post your .csproj.